# Web2py - Sharing a list among modules

Tags: python, performance, web2py

I have a list of id's, that I got from database insertion, to send to other functions in other modules. I have a main module say **asd.py** and I want to share a list **id_list** with the functions in other two modules : **foo.py** and **bar.py** . This is simply:

in asd.py

```
def asd():
    id_list = list()
    # Some insertion then append id_list
    foo.f1(id_list)
    bar.f1(id_list)
```

My question is **id_list**  is copied by value or reference, assume that is a very big list. And is this approach "performance-wise" ?

Thank you.

Comment: performance-wise you might want to [cache the list in memory](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#cache) and avoid loading the list when it's not used. Maybe not all functions in your controllers need your list. In that case you can try [conditional modules](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#markmin_conditional_models), or simply loading the data on demand. Hope this helps to answer the second part of your question.

Comment: @Remco thank you, I didn't look at them.

Comment: @Remco: These are conditional *models*, not modules.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger indeed, my apologies for the wrong word and thanks for pointing out Stefan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Id_list` is copied by reference, although mutable objects are a weird edge-case in this regard. If the `foo.f1` call executes `id_list = 7`, the copy of `id_list` in the `asd` function will not change. However, if `foo.f1` calls `id_list.append(9)`, a `9` will appear at the end of `id_list` in the `asd` function call. There is no implicit copying of the list.

Comment: Thank you @ppperry , I don't change the list, just pass the list to inform other modules.